# Is there any way to get Sublime Text 3 to force all files to open in a new window?

Tags: linux, sublime-text-3, i3-window-manager

Is there any way to force every file to be open in a separate window of Sublime Text 3? I use [i3](https://i3wm.org) and would prefer to have my Sublime Text files open in a tabbed layout of that rather than tabs within Sublime Text.

By this I don’t just mean files opened from outside of Sublime Text, but also files that I open from within the sidebar in Sublime Text.